# Dapper transactions throwing errors before commit

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm executing some statements like this using Dapper (the connection is an NpgsqlConnection):

```
using var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
connection.Execute("INSERT INTO table1(id) VALUES (0);", transaction);
connection.Execute("invalid sql command", transaction);
transaction.Commit();
```

My understanding, based on various Dapper tutorials, was that all the statements should be committed at once when `.Commit()` is called, but I'm getting an `NpgsqlException` immediately when the second statement is executed. When I look at the database, the table is empty so the first statement is not committed either. Does Dapper automatically commit and rollback transactions for you and is it therefore unnecessary to manually call `.Commit()` and `Rollback()` when using Dapper?

Comment: Commit should be explicit, rollback is automatic when not committed

Comment: Is there an example of an error that would require manual rollback; i.e. during the commit instead of prior?

Comment: A scenario: you execute a bunch of statements, then you find you shouldn't have done that and roll back

Comment: Commands are executed immediately but the result is only stored permanently after a commit - that's why you get the error immediately

Comment: This is ADO.Net, not Dapper, doing this. When you have a `using` on the transaction (as you rightly should) it will always attempt a rollback if not yet committed. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbtransaction.dispose?view=netcore-1.1. As long as you have a `using` you are safe with all SQL ADO providers commonly used

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a using statement rollback a database transaction if an error occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641660/will-a-using-statement-rollback-a-database-transaction-if-an-error-occurs) Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388852/is-rollback-automatic-in-a-using-scope-with-c-sharp-sql-server-calls